# Failed to parse source map from @ethersproject and xhr2-cookies file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, web-applications

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from .\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\_version.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\_version.ts'

same thing, but goes for path ending in abi-coder.ts', abstract-coder.ts', address.ts', anonymous.ts', array.ts', boolean.ts', bytes.ts', fixed-bytes.ts', null.ts', number.ts', string.ts', tuple.ts', index.ts', interface.ts'

then I get the same thing for Failed to parse source map from .\node_modules\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\errors.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...node_modules\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\errors.ts'

index.ts', progress-event.ts', xml-http-request-event-target.ts', xml-http-request-upload.ts', xml-http-request.ts'

Each of these files are accompanied by the file name but ending in `.js.map` or nothing and is a Javascript file instead

[image]

I tried this:

`npm i ethers` and
`npm i xhr2-cookies@0.9.1` but it did not change anything.

I had to move some files around to get them in the correct folder set up/ path, but each TS File is named ending in `.d`, but it does not work if I replace it with `.ts` nor remove it all together. Any idea what is going on?

I also tried adding all the dependencies that were missing manually from the `npm list`.

I already fixed `export.module` and `setupMiddlewares` before this.

I only tried changing the names of the first 2 files, but I still got the same errors.

(Update: for some weird reason, the compiler is picking up on _version.ts and abi-coder.ts in the src.ts folder, but everything else is not working. I removed the `.d` here and those work, but I removed it from all the others and restarted my computer and it still does not work.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so what I did was run `npm update ethers` and then I believe it reverted all my changes back to the original file names with the `.d` in the name for the TS files and then I was reading up on the errors and somewhere in there it said run `npm audit fix --force` and then I ran my project again and it worked!

Answer (score -2):

Just sharing another way and simpler that worked for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf yarn.lock
```

and Install everything again