# Failed to parse source map... Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The problem is when I run `yarn start` there are some warnings occur as:

```sh
WARNING in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/providers/transactions/reducer.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/mac/Desktop/react-django-nft-marketplace/react_django_nft_marketplace/frontend/frontend/node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/providers/transactions/reducer.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mac/Desktop/react-django-nft-marketplace/react_django_nft_marketplace/frontend/frontend/node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/providers/transactions/reducer.js.map'
 @ ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/providers/transactions/provider.js 8:0-47 23:46-64
 @ ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/providers/DAppProvider.js 8:0-62 50:29-48
 @ ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/providers/index.js 1:0-31 1:0-31
 @ ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/index.js 2:0-28 2:0-28
 @ ./src/App.tsx 5:0-54 11:30-42 13:24-37 13:39-54
 @ ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24 11:33-36

102 warnings have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.68.0 compiled with 102 warnings in 2298 ms
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Issues checking in progress...
No issues found.
^C
mbp:frontend mac$
```

I've created the react app by running `npx create-react-app frontend --template typescript` command. There is also almost the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538338/failed-to-parse-source-map-from-ethersproject-and-xhr2-cookies-file-error-eno) as of my. But it didn't resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved with the recent update [0.11](https://github.com/EthWorks/useDApp/releases/tag/%40usedapp%2Fcore%400.11.0) of `@usedapp/core` library.

Answer (score 10):

you should try create an .env file in your root directory (same folder as `package.json`) and set `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` on a single line:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Comment: Source maps are helpful while debugging in the browsers devtools, if we supress the source map generation it will be harder to debug