# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory for react-ionicons

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, ionicons

I installed react-ionicons by using the below comment

```
npm i react-ionicons
```

and in my js file, I have the below code. I was able to see the icon in my screen, however in the console. I got lots of error and warning.

```
import { Airplane } from 'react-ionicons'

const res = () => {
            <Airplane
                color={'#fff'} 
                title={'airplane'}
                height="30px"
                width="30px"
            />
}
```

```
.....

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-ionicons/lib/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/az/project1/node_modules/react-ionicons/lib/WomanOutline.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/az/project1/node_modules/react-ionicons/lib/WomanOutline.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-ionicons/lib/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/az/project1/node_modules/react-ionicons/lib//WomanSharp.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/az/project1/node_modules/react-ionicons/lib//WomanSharp.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-ionicons/lib/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/az/project1/node_modules/react-ionicons/lib/index.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/az/project1/node_modules/react-ionicons/lib/index.js.map'

webpack compiled with 1302 warnings
```

Is that mean I did not install react-ionicons correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the fix by the link below
[blog]: [Failed to parse source map... Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986875/failed-to-parse-source-map-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Create the file `.env` in the project folder and type the key

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Comment: you probably also want to comment over on https://github.com/zamarrowski/react-ionicons/issues/78